# Polygon Pour not working in inner layer Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, polygon

When i try to pour plygon in my inner layer the outline of the polygonis only visible .

[image: Screen shot of the pcb]

Can somebody help me to solve this

Comment: Is the layer set up as a signal layer or a plane layer? Is the polygon assigned to the +5V net (and did you tick "Remove dead copper")?

Comment: Also check that it isn't too small (its in the polygon properties - Remove islands less than xxx mm²) and also check if the rule specifies a thermal relief connect or not